# Which version of PHP introduced interfaces?

Tags: php, oop, interface

I'm tempted to use interfaces in my project but am unsure if they work with PHP version 5.2 (which I must support).

What is the minimum version of PHP that will allow me to use interfaces in my code?

**Ref:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: if you are unsure, just write a small class and interface and test it on your target system.

Comment: *Prior to PHP 5.3.9, a class could not implement two interfaces that specified a method with the same name, since it would cause ambiguity. More recent versions of PHP allow this as long as the duplicate methods have the same signature.* - from that page. Or, did you read that already and did not answer your question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It didn't really answer my question because it indicates interfaces were around prior to 5.3.9 but it doesn't give a version.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That quote specifically addresses something about multiple interfaces, not whether the concept of an interface was present or not.

Comment: Then, you've an "answer" given below ;-) which is what I also saw on PHP.net and should have mentioned that also, in addition to my first "comment". *My bad*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- humm, I'm not so sure :( - see my comment to that answer.

Comment: That's why the "comments" area exists in order to get to the *heart of the matter* ;-)

Comment: It sure does! hehe :)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller doing that will give me an indication with reference to my target system, but I'd like to know for future reference. Say my target system changed in my next project. Hence there is some value to asking this question.

Comment: As per a finding on http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/58558-starting-what-version-php-interfaces-supported.html *"From PHP 5.0
These features come with the new object model in PHP 5, see:

PHP: New Object Model - Manual"* http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reading documentation and/or testing it instead of having to resort to the community for easily tested questions like this.

Comment: @PeeHaa then close it if you wish. I don't feel strongly either way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces were introduced in php 5! You can see this in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php

And a quote from there:

> Among the features in **PHP 5** are the inclusions of visibility, abstract and final classes and methods, additional magic methods, **interfaces**, cloning and typehinting.

You can also simply test it here: http://3v4l.org/T2uJU and then you see it also there

Answer (score 2):

The page ["New Functions"](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.functions.php) under the section ["Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x"](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php) lists the function [`get_declared_interfaces()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-interfaces.php) as being added in PHP 5.0. The same version is listed on the documentation page of the function itself.

The function [`interface_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.interface-exists.php) was added on PHP 5.0.2 while [`class_implements()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) appeared on PHP 5.1.0.

The standard interfaces [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and some others appeared on PHP 5.0 while [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) and more specialized iterators appeared on PHP 5.1.0

I think you can safely use interfaces with PHP 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for the answr @axiac. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the links on http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php, interfaces were introduced with PHP version 5.0.